ManyToMany:: How to save data only in the "joining table" and save only “owning side”
There is a Many-to-Many relationship between the "MyUser" and "Roles" tables, with "joining table" = "USERS_ROLES".
When I save "MyUser":: the data is successfully saved to the "MyUser" table, to the "Roles" table and to the "joining table" table.
I do it like this::
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class MyUser {
 ...

  @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
  @JoinTable(name = "USERS_ROLES",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id_pk")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id_pk")})
  private List<Roles> listRoles;
 ...
}

And that's it::
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Roles {
  ...
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="listRoles")
  private List<MyUser> myUsersList;
  ...
}

I want the data to be saved only to the "MyUser" table and to the "joining table", i.e. so that the data is not saved to the "Roles" table.
If I use "CascadeType.REMOVE", an error is thrown. Here it is:: "TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Roles".
Well, that is, the "MyUser" object contains another "Roles" object, I save "MyUser", and I do not save "Roles", so this error is thrown.
Question: so how do I save the data only to the "MyUser" table and to the "joining table" table, i.e. so that the data is not saved to the "Roles" table ?
Does anyone have any ideas?

You should remove CascadeType.PERSIST so that data is only saved to the users table and the USERS_ROLES table and not saved to the roles table.
The TransientObjectException error is most likely occurring because you are persisting MyUser with a manually set identifier, although you specified that identifiers should be generated for this entity.

If I delete CascadeType.PERSIST, the following exception is thrown:: TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: **Roles**

@YuraMazurov The TransientObjectException error is most likely occurring because you are persisting MyUser with a manually set identifier, although you specified that identifiers should be generated for this entity.

:: Entity = MyUser looks like this.  The "id" field has the following generation strategy:: GenerationType.SEQUENCE. If I understood you correctly, then the generation strategy should be replaced with something like GenerationType.AUTO ?

@YuraMazurov You must choose one thing, either remove the generation of identifiers and set them manually, or use the generation, but do not set them manually.

Thank you so much for your help. I will try to do as you said.
